# Display scrolling when the width is less than 800

Tags: html, css, firefox

how to Display scrolling when the width is less than 800 ?

i use :

```
<body style="background-color: #eee;min-width:800px;">
<body>
```

It works in : chrome , Safari , opera and IE but Does not work in FireFox

Firefox does not display scroll

FireFox Version : 25

How do I it compatible in Firefox ?

**update :**

Please see:

display scroll in chrome :
[image: display scroll in chrome :]

display scroll in safari :

[image]

display scroll in Opera :

[image]

Firefox does not display scroll :

[image]

**Firefox is a browser shit.**

Comment: I add it but not worked.....

Comment: do you have enough data on the page to reach that far?

Comment: Yes. Data are Enough. The scroll is displayed in all browsers except Firefox

Comment: You want to show scroll when width is less than 800 or more?

Comment: Would I suggest instead of having it in the body, put your stuff in an element like a div. <div style="background-color: #eee;min-width:800px;"> This is test asdasdasd </div>

Answer (score 0):

Try using this.

```
<body style="background-color: #eee;min-width:800px;overflow:scroll;">
<body>
```

And if doesn't work, try `overlflow: auto;`

Try this -> `overflow-x: scroll`

Comment: Try using overflow-x: scroll;

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any content within your `<body>` element that has a relative position? That's a requirement for Firefox to accept the `min-width` setting. Otherwise the body is 0px high. Something that has no height, can't really have a width – hence no wide element, no scrollbar. So far for Firefox' logic – and I wouldn't call that "browser shit".

So either try to add some content with `position: relative;` or add `min-height: 1px;` to the `<body>`.

Comment: @user3002842 Just tested it again in Firefox and it works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/umNL6/ – Which version of Firefox are you using?

Comment: FireFox Version : 20 and 24 and 25

Comment: Can you provide a full example on jsfiddle? perhaps there are other parts of the CSS that work against this.